# Git fails with libcharset.so.1

Tags: linux, git

Tried several things,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get remove git
sudo apt-get install git

~$ git
git: error while loading shared libraries: libcharset.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

:~$ uname -a
Linux NB128 4.15.0-70-generic #79~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 14:01:10 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Looks like this is centos library. I am not sure why is my git dependent on this.

https://pkgs.org/download/libcharset.so.1()(64bit)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try doing a source-install:

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev asciidoc xmlto docbook2x
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
make all doc info prefix=/usr
sudo make install install-doc install-html install-info install-man prefix=/usr
```

[source](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git#build-git-from-source-on-linux)

It doesn't seem to require a libcharset (at least not directly). So maybe it's worth a try.

Comment: `libcharset` is perhaps a part of `libiconv`.

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev asciidoc xmlto docbook2x
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'zlib1g-dev' instead of 'libz-dev'
E: Unable to locate package asciidoc
E: Unable to locate package xmlto
E: Unable to locate package docbook2x`